# Migrate Q to BlueBird (or Vow)

Tags: node.js, promise, q, bluebird

I'm current using the Q promise library in a Node/amqp app.  I've read that the performance of Q vs libraries like BlueBird or Vow is... not so good.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to use BlueBird (or Vow) to replace my current Q usage patterns.

Here's an example:

```
this.Start = Q(ampq.connect(url, { heartbeat: heartbeat }))
    .then((connection) => {
        this.Connection = connection;
        return Q(connection.createConfirmChannel());
    })
    .then((channel) => {
        this.ConfirmChannel = channel;
        channel.on('error', this.handleChannelError);
        return true;
    });
```

I should've mentioned - I'm using TypeScript...  In this example I'm taking an amqplib promises, and creating a Q promise out of it (because I don't like the amqplib promises).  How do I do that with BlueBird or Vow?

Another example is:

```
public myMethod(): Q.Promise<boolean> {
    var ackDeferred = Q.defer<boolean>();

    var handleChannelConfirm = (err, ok): void => {
        if (err !== null) {
            //message nacked!
            ackDeferred.resolve(false);
        }
        else {
            //message acked
            ackDeferred.resolve(true);
        }
    }

     ...some other code here which invokes callback above...

    return ackDeferred.promise;
}
```

How is that pattern implemented?

So my general questions is:

1. Are the performance differences I've read about true?
2. How do I migrate from Q to BlueBird or Vow, with a focus on those two patterns (but an explanation of using 'then' would be great, too)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, Bluebird is two orders of magnitude faster than Q, and is much more debuggable. You can look at the benchmarks yourself.

As for the code:

- `Q()` maps to `Promise.resolve` in Bluebird (just like in ES6 native promises).*
- `Q.defer` maps to `Promise.defer()` although it's a better option to use the promise constructor or automatic promisification as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises). In short, the promise constructor is throw safe.

Note* - once you've cast the promise, it'll assimilate thenables from other libraries automatically - so this is perfectly fine:

```
this.Start = Promise.resolve(ampq.connect(url, { heartbeat: heartbeat }))
.then((connection) => {
    this.Connection = connection;
    return connection.createConfirmChannel());
})
.then((channel) => {
    this.ConfirmChannel = channel;
    channel.on('error', this.handleChannelError);
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Straight across mapping - I'm off the 'Q'!